# Example for an operator with spectrum $\{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> I'm searching for an example of a Banachspace $X$ and an operator $T\in K(X)/\{0\}$ with spectrum $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$ and one of the following properties:

i) $\sigma_p(T)=\{0\}$

ii) $\sigma_c(T)=\{0\}$

iii) $\sigma_r(T)=\{0\}$

The Banachspaces can be different for every operator which fulfills i), ii) or iii)

For i) I thought about an operator with a Banachspace $X$ with $dim X<\infty$. Because for these Banachspaces $\sigma(T)=\sigma_p(T)$  So for i) I just need an operator T with $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$

Can someone give me an example for the other two problems? Or are there any operators which fulfill these properties? Thanks in advance.

If any definitions aren't clear, I can add them.

Answer (score 1):

Volterra! That should do it!!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the spectrum of an upper-triangular matrix?